# it shows me an error that says "cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type Int"

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, model, typeerror

[this is the code in the left side is the model part of the app named Concentration, in the right side is also the model part of the app named Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di0kv.png)

i'm doing a tutorial of matching cards game in swift. the problem is that in the tutorial is in swift 4 and now i'm using swift 5. idk if the error is because of this. please Help

Comment: you meant "i" (of your for loop) instead of `Int` in that line. It expect a "real Int value", not the "name class Int"

Comment: If you want help with your code you should post it as text in your question.

Answer (score 2):

that is because you are trying to pass Int it is a struct you have to change the code to be like this

`for item in 1...numberOfPairCard{
     let card = Card(identifier: item)
     cards += [card,card]}`